# Porque me arroja Null cuando extraigo un elemento por ID?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var elemento = document.getElementById('parrafo1');

console.log(elemento);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pagina prrona 2</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="java.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Estilos/styles2.css">
</head>
<body >
    <h1 id="parrafo1">Parrafo 1</h1>    
</body>
</html>
```

Y cuando trato de ver el valor de "elemento", me dice "null", ¿que esta pasando? Alguna mala sintaxis?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> Probablemente te este quedando cacheado el documento js sin actualizar, por eso estas viendo el error. Debido a que aca abajo hice una copia exacta de lo que publicaste y anda bien. En la consola se puede ver el elemento.

Sugerencias para evitar esto:

- Tratá siempre de probar los codigos en ventanas de incogito
- Actualizá tu navegador con `ctrl+f5` (no solo `f5`)
- Instalar algun addon del navegador que limpie la cache del sitio para que no te pasen esas cosas (por ejemplo `clear caché` https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-cache/cppjkneekbjaeellbfkmgnhonkkjfpdn?hl=es

```js
var elemento = document.getElementById('parrafo1');
console.log(elemento)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pagina prrona 2</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="java.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Estilos/styles2.css">
</head>
<body >
    <h1 id="parrafo1">Parrafo 1</h1>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Otra opcion seria que tengas mal la ruta a tu archivo javascript, por eso no te funciona, en ese caso tendria que ver como es la estructura de tu sitio

Comment: Ps si, es lo primero, que me recomiendas para solucionar eso?

Comment: Te estaba quedando guardado en caché la version del javascript sin actualizar? Ahi edite la pregunta con sugerencias para evitar que te pase

Comment: Ahh ok Bro gracias, ps la verdad es que lo probé en un código un poco extenso y luego lo probé en ese todo sencillo y quede desconcertado  Jajajajaj

Comment: Esta solución no es necesariamente correcta. Tu código funciona porque el `snippet` de la respuesta ejecuta primero el código HTML y luego procesa el código de Javascript. El problema del OP parece ser que carga el código JS primero y el mismo se ejecuta antes de que el DOM esté totalmente cargado en memoria. Por eso obtiene un `undefined`. Por favor revisa tu respuesta. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Lo que pasa es que el script js está cargando antes que los elementos HTML del body y por eso no detecta el elemento con el id `parrafo1`.

Tendrias que ubicar el script de la siguiente manera:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pagina prrona 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Estilos/styles2.css">
</head>
<body >
    <h1 id="parrafo1">Parrafo 1</h1>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="java.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ahora si debería de detectar el elemento `h1` con el id `parrafo1`.

Answer (score 2):

El problema seguramente es que el script esta siendo cargado antes de que se cargue la pagina completa, para poder que funcione deberas encerrar tu código javascript dentro de la funcion load:

```js
window.onload = ()=>{
    var elemento = document.getElementById('parrafo1');
    console.log(elemento);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pagina prrona 2</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="java.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Estilos/styles2.css">
</head>
<body >
    <h1 id="parrafo1">Parrafo 1</h1>    
</body>
</html>
```

Aquí funciona tu código tal cual **sin ponerle load** supongo porque stackoverflow primero carga el dom entero y luego el script, pero en una pagina abierta en local puede no funcionar.